# Why don't the corrections to energy disappear in perturbation theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, perturbation-theory

The corrections to the wavefunctions and energies depend on

$<\psi_m^0\,| \,H'|\psi_n^0>$

to some order. I would've thought that

$<\psi_m^0\,| \,H'|\psi_n^0> \, =\, <H' \psi_m^0\,|\psi_n^0>\,=\lambda <\psi_m^0\,|\psi_n^0> = \lambda \cdot 0 = 0$ for $m \neq n$.

where $\lambda$ is some eigenvalue of $H'$. Could someone point out the flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: The states you are looking at are *not*  eigenstates of *H'* , in general.

Comment: @CosmasZachos oh right, I completely missed that. Thank you!

Comment: @CosmasZachos I know it's short and simple, but that comment should probably be an answer (so the OP can mark it as the accepted answer and the question can be considered dealt with by the system).

Comment: @StephenG  One might expect it to be retracted?

Comment: @CosmasZachos My experience is that OPs generally don't delete questions like this and in any case I think your answer is worth keeping anyway.